# How to add flag variable based on source

Tags: sql, compiler-flags

I want to union two tables and add a flag column(1,0) indicating where they came from. Any help on how to perform this SQL?

Comment: would you be able to provide what you have tried?
or maybe the schema of the tables you are trying to union?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a static column to your SELECT

```
SELECT
    a
    ,b
    ,0 AS flag
FROM
    t1
UNION ALL
SELECT
    a
    ,b
    ,1 AS flag
FROM
    t2
```

Answer (score 0):

select 0 my_flag, your_column from your_table_1
union all
select 1 my_aflag, your _column from your_table_2

Comment: Thank you, your code is very useful to create two flag variables. Is there a way to create one common flag variable that has value of 1 or 0 based on the datasource? or a way to combine those two variables into one?